# How to get the full WWW-Authenticate header using the Dot-NET HttpClient?

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, dotnet-httpclient, www-authenticate

## Scenario

I am working on a web program for Windows Phone 8 (not that I think it matters) and using [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)

## The problem

When the user tries to GET the URL, I need to know what type of authentication is needed when the response is a 401.
This is very easy if it is NTLM, Basic, Digest, etc; all of the supported [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383144(v=vs.85).aspx) schemes.
You can the use the the following code to GET the URL:

```
HttpResponseMessage response;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler))
{
     HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, authenticationUri);
     response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
}
```

The easiest way to check which authentication is needed is using the `Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Contains` method, e.g. to check if `NTLM` scheme is required:

```
string scheme = "NTLM";
bool requiredScheme = response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Contains(new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(scheme));
```

If the `scheme = "Bearer"` then it always gives false.

## Obtaining the response header

The following was obtained when trying to access a server that needs `Azure Active Directory` authentication.

### Jason Chrome App

Using the [Jason Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jason/oealdlhfjifhgbmjnenhkgffglaibojf)  to get the response headers from the web-server, I received:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Fri, 10 Oct 2014 11:39:02 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common",
    error="invalid_token", 
    error_description="The access token is missing", 
    NTLM
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
```

### Dot-Net Http Client

Using the HttpClient the `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage` (`response`) gives:

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
      Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
      WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
      X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
      X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
      Date: Fri, 10 Oct 2014 11:25:04 GMT
      Content-Length: 1293
      Content-Type: text/html
    }
```

### WWW-Authenticate Comparison

From the above results the the following comparison can be made.

#### Jason Chrome App

> Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common",
>   error="invalid_token", 
>   error_description="The access token is missing",
>
> NTLM

#### Dot-Net Http Client

> NTLM

The Bearer part is thrown away by the Http Client (or maybe this is a restriction of the `HttpResponseMessage`) and only NTLM authentication is left.

## Question

How or where do I get the full WWW-Authenticate header using the Dot-NET HttpClient that shows all the schemes with their content? This example is specific to Bearer; however, other (custom) schemes also exist.

Any ideas?

---

#### Additional

This same issue seems to be persistent even on [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639)

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using: Visual Studio 2013 with Update 3. Version 4.5.51641

Comment: Is there a public server that requires this sort of authentication we can test against? Does this provide the missing value; var value = r.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Where((h) => h.Scheme == "NTLM").First().Parameter

Comment: @Yort I don't know of a public server, the issue isn't with the NTLM, that  scheme is a supported `WinHTTP` authentication type. The issue is with any scheme that's **NOT** a supported `WinHTTP` authentication type, such as Bearer.